# Customization of column header in view-based NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

Is there any method to change appearance of header in columns of view-based `NSTableView`? I need my custom height of table header, font, colour and position of column title. It seems impossible because in view-based table view you can't change `NSTableHeaderCell` of `NSTableColumn` (in docs for `-setHeaderCell` said "This method is only valid for cell-based table views"), and i don't know any other method for access to appearance of header.

I could hide table header and create special cell imitating header of columns, but in this way i missing splitter line between columns in header therefore i can't resize columns.

Also i know i can subclass of `NSTableHeaderView`, but it only helps me change a height of header. I don't know how to display my custom titles with it. Maybe i miss something.

Comment: IMHO the doc-text is wrong. In my table header I replaced all header cells with my header cells (subclass of NSTableHeaderCell with new draw methods) and it works perfectly for cell based and for view based tableViews / outlineViews. My hint: use -setHeaderCell, give it a try.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Post an answer and i will accept it. p.s. thanks Apple for great docs...